# how to grep or sed a phrase that starts with =user / =Email and ends with &

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I got .`txt` file with captured data which includes some usernames and passwords. One line f.e

```
user=testuser&password=somefunnyletters&cookie=true
```

I need to get just the phrase *user=testuser* without the rest.
To get this line i've used `grep ^user= mylogfile.txt`. I've tried with

```
egrep -e "user=.*&" mylogfile.txt
```

but got the same result.

I'm a newbie in the bash and grep. Could you help me? :)

EDIT:
Thanks guys for answers
Your solution with sed is even better :)

```
2016-01-19 10:34:53,707 POST Data (www.example.com):
user=testuser
2016-01-19 10:35:05,800 POST Data (accounts.google.com):
Page=SignIn
2016-01-19 10:35:11,118 SECURE POST Data (accounts.google.com):
Page=SignIn
2016-01-19 10:35:24,273 POST Data (mail.example.com):
username=ACCOUNT2
```

There's a pice of my log.txt

```
  2016-01-19 10:35:05,800 POST Data (accounts.google.com):
Page=SignIn&GALX=4sniYBF1KS4&gxf=AFoagUUWrsxLske465iHUiS7iLFTghUUVA%3A1453195970318&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&rm=false&ltmpl=default&scc=1&ss=1&osid=1&checkedDomains=youtube&checkConnection=&pstMsg=1&_utf8=%E2%98%83&bgresponse=%21eXpCtDFcUk0RqTZEOIof1FvHKm8CAAAAfVIAAAAPCgBHGejcPtA_v4HvVc7ixkq7wxLdz6ZvzEljoDpRfUwMD_czUNuCDpeVoBlAC77pd_nqcMFOMx6CkFDSBsZ1oCvv1M2h9WokdDkqANw3H-8BGAog77GOKPHJHR-FDUo5vutu5SKbkioAXvel_pcJOttUSp6glPAFQswWhastRHyyRn9axImbsoKlYsob3h604WklobLZNjQVbf9_cS1jbMQE-XWYBPE1FRXQzQysqKBLGHAmCUHvlaQfxYs1NsxAwmkNLoRBDAefVHTNT4YHqKEJ0LNkun8BnyxKT0jPTj7AebLpRUclWa9jF1FuVuakfi6ZbpqJnLK0XCFyQ8maiHvQh_SraectIJg_n4hBMkQ_riKZtRWPZCghzRS87Q3xezq2l-grUgO-&pstMsg=1&dnConn=&checkConnection=&checkedDomains=youtube&Email=EXAMPLEMAILUSER&Passwd=ewuoieuroiuio&signIn=Sign+in&PersistentCookie=yes&rmShown=1
```

Is there any possibility to get this

```
2016-01-19 10:35:05,800 POST Data (accounts.google.com):
```

and the Email=EXAMPLEMAILUSER ?

I need to get Email= , user=  and username= . It would be nice to get for which site is username/email :)

It would help me a lot ;)

Comment: `sed` is always an option: `sed 's/\&.*$//' filename`.

Comment: Parsing a query string using existing tools is also an option!

Comment: Point well taken, but I've yet to see a box with `grep` that doesn't usually also have `sed` installed by default as well. That's probably the reason it was noted as a *comment* and not an *answer*.

Comment: Don't edit your question to add a new question; ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -oP 'user=\K[^&]*'
```

or

```
grep -oP '^[^=]*=\K[^&]*' file
```

check this example:

```
kent$  echo "user=testuser&password=somefunnyletters&cookie=true"|grep -oP 'user=\K[^&]*'
testuser

kent$  echo "user=testuser&password=somefunnyletters&cookie=true"|grep -oP '^[^=]*=\K[^&]*'
testuser
```

Tested with grep:

```
kent$  grep --version|head -1
grep (GNU grep) 2.22
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It shows me what i need :)
Could you explain me how  how this 'K' works?

Comment: @uxez `\K` works only for `grep -P (PCRE)` it works similar as look-behind, but supports dynamic length.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SED:

```
sed 's/&.*//' mylogfile.txt
```

Find the first '&' and everything after it (s/&.*/) and replace by 'empty' (//)

Comment: Your solution is even better, because it gave me more info.